# Installing SSH via Cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I have a laptop with windows 8. I'm trying to setup SSH from this laptop to a windows 2012 server via Cygwin64.

I followed the steps as described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/).

However, when I am at the step: `ssh-user-config`, I get the error:

```
ERROR: There is no home directory set for you in /etc/passwd.<br>
ERROR: Setting $HOME is not sufficient!
```

In my Cygwin64 installation folder, I see a directory home with a user that is copied from the windows user I'm logged in with (say this user is nifty).

I also see a file `cygwin64/etc/passwd` - but in the file my windows user (nifty) is not present.

The only line I see there is:

```
[computername]+sshd:*:197610:197121:[computername]\sshd,S-1-5-21-1837826546-2281981055-3577963604-1002:/var/empty:/bin/false
```

I have tried to manually add the passwd file, inserting:

```
nifty:*:1:1:/home/nifty:/bin/bash/
```

I also tried to add:

```
[computername]++sshd:*:1:1::/home/swuyts:/bin/bash
```

When googling, the only thing I come up with is try to run this command:

```
mkpasswd -l -u >> /etc/passwd
```

I noticed this adds some accounts present in windows (such as the administrators group, system account and the created cyg_server from the step above), but it doesn't help me in letting me execute ssh-user-config.

Can somebody explain me how to proceed?

Comment: Is your account a local account or a domain account? If the latter, try `mkpasswd -d`.  `mkpasswd -c` looks interesting too.

Comment: Is your username `nifty` or `swuyts` or something else?  They don't match in your question.  i.e. why did you mention `/home/swuyts`?

Comment: @Mikel: mkpasswd -c did the job. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

This is a temporary problem.  The `ssh-user-config` script needs a fix.

The reason your "How To Geek" tutorial doesn't match your experience is that the most recent release of Cygwin (1.7.34) did away with `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` in the default installation. It is possible to recreate them, as you eventually discovered, but if they aren't present, the Cygwin DLL uses the Windows native user/group databases: [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) if present, or [SAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Accounts_Manager) if not.

This script is making an outdated assumption, being that it can just run the contents of `/etc/passwd` through `awk` to answer questions.

Cygwin recently got a new `getent(1)` program which works like the one on Linux, abstracting away the differences between the `/etc` files, AD, and SAM. The script just needs patches to use this tool instead of parsing `/etc` files.

As we say on the Cygwin mailing lists, [PTC](https://cygwin.com/acronyms/#PTC)!

Answer (score 0):

Please try re-running the `setup.exe` to update to the `openssh-6.7p1-2`.
This should fix your issue.

Also, the origin of the issue (`setup.exe` choosing "prev" version for first install of a package instead of current one) has been resolved.

Comment: Are you sure that's all that's needed? I thought we were still waiting on an update to `csih` from Corinna.

Comment: Yes, Warren. I checked this. And this was my bugreport, amongst other, that helped to nail and resolve the issue :)